# Where did the "Create AndroidManifest.xml" button go in Qt Creator 3.3.0?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator

There used to be a "Create AndroidManifest.xml" button in Projects->Run->Deploy:

[image]

But now as of QtCreator 3.3.0 with Qt 5.4.0, it's nowhere to be found:

[image]

How do I specify an AndroidManifest.xml now that the button is gone?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You now do it from Projects -> Build -> Build Android APK -> Create Templates.

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-deploying-android.html):

> You can use the qmake variables to specify all the settings you need for the androiddeployqt tool and you do not need an Android manifest file until you want to publish the package in an application store. To specify additional settings for APK packages, you can create an Android manifest file and edit it in Qt Creator. Select Create Templates to create the file and to open it in the Android Manifest Editor.

[image]

Comment: what do we do after we click 'create templates'?